# Same style for every row in Android's TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way in Android XML to set the same style (or style paramerers, like padding) for all rows in a TableLayout at once?

What I would like to avoid doing is:

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow style="@style/MyStyle">...</TableRow>
    <TableRow style="@style/MyStyle">...</TableRow>
    <TableRow style="@style/MyStyle">...</TableRow>
    <TableRow style="@style/MyStyle">...</TableRow>
    ...
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define your own styles by creating XML files on the res/values directory. So, let's suppose you want to have red and bold text, then you create a file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyRedTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyRedTextAppearance</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyRedTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

You can name it like you want, for instance `res/values/red.xml`. Then, the only thing you have to do is using that view in the widgets that you want, for instance:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
        style="@style/MyRedTheme"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="This is red, isn't it?"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

For more referense [click here](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/)